# Is there a way to add a hyperlink in a div?

Tags: html

I'm trying to add a sidebar to my website, but I can't add links in my sidebar div. When adding an hyperlink tag to my div, VSC gives me no errors, but it won't show up when I open the HTML file.

Comment: Can you share your relevant html code? Please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

do `<a href="http://somethingsomethinglink" >link blue text that brings you to website on click</a>`

the `<a>` tag is for links, you can put in in your `<div>`

Comment: note that VSC won't show you some errors when editing HTML, as it may interpret that you are trying to do something else, like adding text that aren't links

Comment: I actually have other text in my div.

Answer (score 0):

This happened because you might didn't gave content in your anchor tag. Let's see an example.

```
<a href='link'>Content for displaying on the web</a>
```

Without content, it will not show on your web page. On the other hand, without `href` value, it will not go anywhere.